# pthreads stopping already running thread once a condition has been met

Tags: php, pthreads

I'm still relatively new to PHP and trying to use pthreads to solve an issue. I have 20 threads running processes that end at varying times. Most finish around < 10 seconds or so. I don't need all 20, just 10 detected. Once I get to 10, I would like to kill the threads, or to continue on to the next step.

I have tried using set_time_limit to about 20 seconds for each of the threads, but they ignore it and keep running. I am looping through the jobs looking for the join because I didn't want the rest of the program to run but I'm stuck until the slowest one has finished. While pthreads has reduced the time from around a minute to about 30 seconds, I can shave even more time since the first 10 run in about 3 seconds.

Thanks for any help and here is my code:

```
$count = 0;
    foreach ( $array as $i ) {
        $imgName = $this->smsId."_$count.jpg";
        $name = "LocalCDN/".$imgName;
        $stack[] = new AsyncImageModify($i['largePic'], $name);
        $count++;
    }

    // Run the threads
    foreach ( $stack as $t ) {
        $t->start();
    }

    // Check if the threads have finished; push the coordinates into an array
    foreach ( $stack as $t ) {
        if($t->join()){
            array_push($this->imgArray, $t->data);

        }

    }

class class AsyncImageModify extends \Thread{
public $data;

public function __construct($arg, $name, $container) {
    $this->arg = $arg;
    $this->name = $name;

}

public function run() {
//tried putting the set_time_limit() here, didn't work
    if ($this->arg) {
        // Get the image
        $didWeGetTheImage = Image::getImage($this->arg, $this->name);
        if($didWeGetTheImage){
            $timestamp1 = microtime(true);
            print_r("Starting face detection $this->arg" . "\n");
            print_r(" ");
            $j = Image::process1($this->name);
            if($j){
                // lets go ahead and do our image manipulation at this point
                $userPic = Image::process2($this->name, $this->name, 200, 200, false, $this->name, $j);
                if($userPic){
                    $this->data = $userPic;
                    print_r("Back from process2; the image returned is $userPic");
                }
            }
            $endTime = microtime(true);
            $td = $endTime-$timestamp1;
            print_r("Finished face detection $this->arg in $td seconds" . "\n");
            print_r($j);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to guess the functionality of Image::* methods, so I can't really answer in any detail.

What I can say, is that there are very few machines I can think of that are suitable to run 20 concurrent threads in any case. A more suitable setup would be the worker/stackable model. A Worker thread is a reuseable context, and can execute task after task, implemented as Stackables; execution in a multi-threaded environment should always use the least amount of threads to get the most work done possible.

[Please see pooling example](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/examples/Pooling.php) and other [examples](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/tree/master/examples) that are distributed with pthreads, available on [github](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads), additionally, much information regarding usage is contained in past bug reports, if you are still struggling after that ...